# 3 column 3 row HTML table breaks in Mobile Safari but works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, ios, html-table, mobile-safari, pseudo-element

### Chrome & Firefox

[image]

### Mobile Safari on IOS 14

[image]

`Z-index` seems to be ignored and it appears as though the `pseudo elements` aren't anchored correctly to the `tbody` element and stretch well beyond their parent.

What can be adjusted so Mobile Safari behaves similarly to Chrome and Firefox? I'm using `pseudo elements` to mimic the appearance of overlapping table rows. If this look can be achieved without the use of those `pseudo elements` that's also a solution that works for me.

```css
th:first-child, tbody td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
th:last-child, tbody td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody, tbody td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale( 1 );
}
tbody td {
  background-color: #333;
}
tbody td:first-child, tfoot td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody td:last-child, tfoot td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody::before, tbody::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; left: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  content: "";
}
tbody::after {
  top: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: #444;
}
tfoot td { background-color: #444; }
```

```html
<style>
  html, table, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    color: #ddd;
  }
  html {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
  table, th, td {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  thead th {
    background-color: #222;
  }
  th { text-transform: uppercase; }
  td { border-bottom: solid #222; }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> <th><p>one</p></th><th><p>two</p></th><th><p>three</p></th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td><p>four</p></td><td><p>five</p></td><td><p>six</p></td> </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr> <td><p>seven</p></td><td><p>eight</p></td><td><p>nine</p></td> </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an issue with how the `tbody` element is rendered in Safari.

Getting rid of the `pseudo elements` completely and instead using a `linear-gradient` with hard stops on the `table` element itself behind the table cells seems to provide the same result as the desktop browsers without any issues in Mobile Safari.

```css
th:first-child, tbody td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
th:last-child, tbody td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody, tbody td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale( 1 );
}
tbody td {
  background-color: #333;
}
tbody td:first-child, tfoot td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody td:last-child, tfoot td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tfoot td { background-color: #444; }
table {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient( 
      transparent 30%, #222 30% 50%, #444 50% 70%, transparent 70% 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<style>
  html, table, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    color: #ddd;
  }
  html {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
  table, th, td {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
   thead th {
    background-color: #222;
  }
  th { text-transform: uppercase; }
  td { border-bottom: solid #222; }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> <th><p>one</p></th><th><p>two</p></th><th><p>three</p></th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td><p>four</p></td><td><p>five</p></td><td><p>six</p></td> </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr> <td><p>seven</p></td><td><p>eight</p></td><td><p>nine</p></td> </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```